# SQL Join data count from another tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have database

**From tabel userlist**

```
NO NAMA DATE
1  THIS 2019-01-17 18:40:45
2  IS   2019-01-17 18:40:45
3  NAME 2019-02-17 18:40:45
```

**From tabel usertext**

```
ID TEXT CREATE
1  THIS 2019-01-18 18:40:45
2  IS   2019-02-21 18:40:45
3  TEXT 2019-03-19 18:40:45
```

how to return like this with *sql query*

```
Month Name Text
Jan   2    1
Feb   1    1
Mar   0    1
```

i already try this

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(userlist.date) as Month, COUNT(userlist.no) as name, COUNT(usertext.id) as text FROM userlist, usertext WHERE MONTH(userlist.date) < 12 AND YEAR(userlist.date) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) GROUP BY MONTHNAME(date)
```

and return like this

```
Month Name Text
Jan   1    1
Feb   1    1
Mar   1    1
```

Comment: Store dates using a date data type. Then see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry I already change **date type** at my database and question, still return with same data

Comment: Format your code properly.  No one is going to read a one-liner code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Union, then aggregate.

```
SELECT Month, SUM(usr) as Name, SUM(txt) as Text
FROM
(
    SELECT MONTH(t.date) AS monthnum, MONTHNAME(t.date) AS Month, 1 AS usr, 0 AS txt
    FROM userlist t
    WHERE YEAR(t.date) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
      AND MONTH(t.date) < 12 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT MONTH(t.create) AS monthnum, MONTHNAME(t.create) AS Month, 0 AS usr, 1 AS txt
    FROM usertext t
    WHERE YEAR(t.create) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
      AND MONTH(t.create) < 12
) q
GROUP BY monthnum, Month
ORDER BY monthnum
```

And below a little piece of sql that generates 12 months.  It could be an extra UNION ALL in the inner query, to fill gaps for the missing months.

```
select n as monthnum, monthname(100*n+1) as month, 0 as usr, 0 as txt
from (
    select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9 union all select 10 union all select 11 union all select 12
) q
```

Comment: sry about this, how can i show all months even if no data?

Comment: @ilhamrisky21  Ah, if you're missing months in both tables then that's a little harder. Often when gaps in data need to be filled in the result then a reference table is used, one that has no gaps. And then LEFT JOIN the data with gaps to that.  But in my current solution there might be an easier trick.  Just UNION ALL an extra query that has all months &  0 usr  & 0 txt.

Comment: sorry I asked again, I used union all that you demonstrated, but why does he duplicate every time there is data, for example

September 2
September 0

Comment: A "September, 0, 0" would be generated if that 2nd extra query was put in the first query? At least if the 2 tables don't have September.

Answer (score 2):

You could try joining the subquery for count

```
select  t1.my_month month, t2.count_name, t3.count_text
from( 
  select  month(create ) my_month
  from userlist
  union  
  select  month(create) 
  from usertext
) t1 
left join  (
 select month(create) month, count(*) count_name
 from  userlist 
 group by month(create)
) t2 on t2.month  = t1.my_month
left join  (
 select month(create) month, count(*) count_text
 from  usertext
 group by month(create)
) t3 on t3.month  = t1.my_month
```

Comment: show me the exact error message anyway answer  update  .. missing dot t3.count_text